# Unable to allocate array with shape and data type int32 in python console

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, memory, numpy-ndarray

I have been working with large datasets lately. First I was working on jupyter notebook on a windows machine where I was creating an array with shape (30072, 15484) and data type int32 and it was able to create it successfully. But when I ran the same code on the python console using the command prompt it gave a memory error. Why so?

I am running the following line 
`pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((30000,15000),dtype=object))`

Answer (score 0):

You are using your code with dtype=object which takes more time to create than a simple int32 type. I tested your code with my PC it works fine with vscode, jupyter and cmd. Try this code:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((30000,15000),dtype="int32"))
```

Comment: Thanks but that was not the issue. The issue was due to python 32-bit architecture. I was running jupyter notebook on 64-bit architecture and python console was 32bit